# Share login data/cookies between multiple installations

Tags: login

I have a WordPress installation at the document root for [a domain](http://www.bradleycountypulse.com), and then an additional installation in [an immediate subdirectory](http://www.bradleycountypulse.com/classifieds) of that installation such that I may use different themes for the two. I want to link the two sites logins so that you don't have to login twice in order to use both sites.

My coding skills are not great, so an easy fix or an of the shelf plugin are preferred.

Comment: Are you talking about a subdomain, or simply a sub-directory? A subdomain would be something along the lines of `subdomain.bradleycountypulse.com`, but all you mention is the `/classifieds` sub-directory (or URL component). Assuming that both URLs use the same WordPress installation and same database, there is no reason that the two would not already share the same login session... Have you installed WordPress twice? Is there any reason that you _need_ to have two separate WordPress installations?

Comment: Playing around with your linked site, it appears to me as though you do indeed have two seperate WordPress installations - one located at `bradleycountypulse.com` and the other at `bradleycountypulse.com/classifieds`. Or is this a single multisite installation?

Comment: I had to use two installs because of the unique features of the classifieds page, a special theme was needed.

Comment: I wanted to use the sahifa theme for the main site, and then have classifieds pick up after clicking that link

Comment: In the event you need multiple sites for, e.g., a company intranet that needs to share logins, the [Google Apps Login plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-apps-login/) is perfect (if your company uses Google Apps, o' course).

Answer (score 5):

You can share user tables between different WordPress installations by installing the second site ("Site B") to use the original site's ("Site A") database, then choosing to use an alternate table prefix during installation so as to keep the rest of the data separate.

The second part of the problem is sharing login cookies between the two installations (what WordPress uses to keep track of login/"session" data). In order to do this, you must use the same cookie-path for both sites.

After installation, open the `wp-config.php` file in Site B's installation root, and add (or replace) the following lines shortly after the database configuration, modifying them as needed to fit your configuration:

```
$cookiehash = md5("http://www.bradleycountypulse.com/");  // Use Site A's URL

define(CUSTOM_USER_TABLE,'wp_users');           //Change 'wp' to match the prefix set during
define(CUSTOM_USER_META_TABLE,'wp_usermeta');   //  Site A's installation
define('COOKIEPATH', '/');                      //This path should reference Site A's root
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '/');                  //Should match 'COOKIEPATH'
define('COOKIEHASH', $cookiehash );
```

**Note** that this will only work if the two installations reside on the same domain (which yours do!).

An alternate solution would be to setup the entire system as a single [multisite installation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).

Still another solution (albeit one that requires more legwork) would be to employ [custom page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) on a single installation.

Comment: Thank you, I *think* I can handle that! I will delete the second WP install and attempt to share databases.

Comment: Sure thing! Let me know how it goes - I've never actually done this myself. We may need to do a little finagling to get everything working properly.

Comment: thank you for this! I've been looking at 10s of solutions and no combination worked except this.

Comment: I know this hasn't been updated in a while, but is it possible to use this method on a website that is already on a subdomain?

Comment: @WeirdMike it should work as long as both sites share the same TLD. To use this method though, you'll have to do a little bit of a fancy database merge. The contents of the `users` and `usermeta` tables from the child site need added to the parent site's tables, respectively - but ID conflicts will need to be resolved. You might be able to use WordPress's import/export tool for this purpose. The rest of the child site's tables then need to be added to the parent db, giving them a new table prefix to keep them seperate from the parent's tables. Then, any field in the child site's new tables

Comment: referencing a user by ID will need to be updated to use that user's new, post-merge ID. Finally, alter the child site's `wp-config.php` as detailed in my answer - additionally specifying the new table prefix. Additionally, redefine your child site's salts to [new values](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/) to invalidate old cookies. After that I *believe* everything should be peachy - though I haven't played with doing this in quite some time.

Comment: The largest challenge would likely be the user merge, which could be a very simple or somewhat complex process, depending on your specific set-up and needs

Comment: what if the installations are in different databases?

Answer (score 1):

I have released a wordpress plugin based on the following article:

http://subinsb.com/set-same-cookie-on-different-domains

**User Session Synchronizer** allows you to **keep the user logged in from one wordpress to another** by synchronizing user data and **cookie session** based on a verified email.

The **user email is encrypted** based on the current user ip and a secret key shared by the synchronized wordpress installations.

You can find the plugin here:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-session-synchronizer/

And participate here:

https://github.com/rafasashi/user-session-synchronizer