# How to find the value of the user password in wordpress and send it to another server via rest api

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

If there is some variable from the user's password, I want the password that the user has entered for the wordpress account, to send to another server, so that the user can also log on to another server with the same data as on the wordpress, is there anyone a solution for this? thank you all for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress is not storing the password in the database in the readable format, so you can't simply get the password for any user. Passwords are stored in the hashed format, and they can't be reversed back to a readable format.

Comment: Ok it is clear to me, is there a possibility to send the same password to another server? use the same variable that was made for this field or something like that?

Comment: Pozdrav Srdjane! If the password needs to be shared between WordPress websites, it is possible to share hashed password cookie if both websites share security salts. If the other website is not WordPress, there is no way to match the same cookie/hash for the password. Another possibility is to grab passwords when users set them (creating an account or changing password), and send them then, but that would require creating code to grab passwords and store them in the clear somewhere so they can be used in REST API, and that is very, very bad idea. Passwords should never be stored in the clear.

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed before,   there are a number of options such as Wordpress Multisite installations which can handle this for you.

Or have a read of this solution : [Share login data/cookies between multiple installations](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131399/share-login-data-cookies-between-multiple-installations)